# Justify Using Spannable String Into TextView Android

Tags: android, fonts, typeface, spannablestring, justify

First, I already know that we can use HTML and CSS to justify the text. [Implementation in this library](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android)

However, I need to justify inside of my `AutoResizeTextView` and I found it is incompatible if I use the library above. I use many font styles and various font size, and I want them to fit the text area width. [slight picture of what I am trying to do](http://backgroundimagesfree.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/cool-quotes-wide-wallpaper.jpg)

I am using several `Spannable Strings`, and give those spans various effect and then combine those span into an AutoResizeTextview. 
The weakness I found so far: Different `Typefaces`, that has same font size can have different width and hard to justify..

When I wanted to measure my font size on AutoResizeTextView in order to give each span different font size (In the hope, it can have same width with other spans), the program stops suddenly.. (Maybe its because I have many Typefaces inside an AutoResizeTextView).

```
paint.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface());
float textSize = textView.getTextSize();
paint.setTextSize(textSize);
```

Other thing I tried but also failed..

```
Paint paint = new Paint();    
Rect bounds = new Rect();
        float textSize = 12;
        paint.setTypeface(f1);
        paint.setTextSize(textSize);
        paint.getTextBounds(line1, 0, line1.length(), bounds);
        while (bounds.width() > auto_text.getWidth())
        {
            textSize--;
            paint.setTextSize(textSize);
            paint.getTextBounds(line1, 0, line1.length(), bounds);
        }

        Log.e("Textsize ", "=" +textSize);
```

So, how to make the text become justify like picture above using span? Any idea how?